# UIResponder Signal

Tags: swift, swift-playground

Boa tarde,

fiz uma pequena app com o swift 2.3 Xcode 7.3.1.
com a actualização do swift 3 e Xcode 8 começou a apresentar o erro abaixo.
alguma ajuda por favor.

[image: Print Scr]

Comment: tinha botões mal conectados, reconectei e resolveu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Thread 1: signal SIGABRT significa que você está fazendo alguma requisição para algo que não existe ou não está bem definido. Ocorre, por exemplo, quando você não conecta os botões do storyboard com o código apropriadamente; quando apaga modifica o nome de uma função associada a algum elemento no storyboard, mas esquece de desfazer o link antigo pelo storyboard (ele não detecta automaticamente mudanças, você precisa apagá-las manualmente). Confira se nada do tipo está acontecendo.

Comment: Acabei de perceber depois. Obrigado